# how to display images from sqlite through drawable

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-image

I want to display images from column 'images' in 'penyakit' table from sqlite database. That image display through TabGambar.java.

My friend told me than I can put address of image in database and save that image in drawable. But I don't understand how it works. I have tried to use string uri drawable but it can only display one image for all.

Previously, I had been looking for references on google and find so many tutorials. But I still don't get which part should I add or change. Can somebody help my problem?

This is my works.

TabGambar.java

```
public class TabGambar extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.tabgambar, container, false);
        configureTextView(view);

        return view;
    }

    private void configureTextView(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView namapenyakit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namapenyakit);
        ImageView gambarpenyakit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gambarpenyakit);

          Bundle b = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
          if (b != null)
          {

              namapenyakit.setText(b.getString("nama_penyakit"));


              String uri = "@drawable/ayam1"; 
              int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getActivity().getPackageName());
              Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
              gambarpenyakit.setImageDrawable(res);

          }
}

}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteAssetHelper { 
 //nama database, versi, dan nama tabel yang akan dibuat.
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pakarayam";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private static final String tabel_gejala = "gejala";
 public static final String  kd_gejala  = "kode_gejala";
 public static final String  nm_gejala = "nama_gejala";

 private static final String tabel_penyakit = "penyakit";
 public static final String  kd_penyakit  = "kode_penyakit";
 public static final String  nm_penyakit = "nama_penyakit";
 public static final String  deskripsi = "deskripsi";
 public static final String  solusi = "solusi";
 public static final String  gambar = "gambar";

 private static final String tabel_rule = "rule";
 public static final String  kd_rule  = "kode_rule";
 public static final String  ko_gejala  = "kode_gejala";
 public static final String  ko_penyakit  = "kode_penyakit";
 public static final String  nilai_mb  = "nilai_mb";
 public static final String  nilai_md  = "nilai_md";

 private static DBAdapter dbInstance;
 private static SQLiteDatabase db;

 private DBAdapter(Context context)
 {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 public static DBAdapter getInstance(Context context)
 {
  if (dbInstance == null)
  {
   dbInstance = new DBAdapter(context);
   db = dbInstance.getWritableDatabase();
  }
  return dbInstance;
 }

 @Override
 public synchronized void close()
 {
  super.close();
  if (dbInstance != null)
  {
   dbInstance.close();
  }
 }

 public ArrayList<Gejala> getAllGejala()
 {  
  ArrayList<Gejala> listGejala = new ArrayList<Gejala>();

  Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_gejala, new String[] {kd_gejala, nm_gejala
     }, null, null, null, null, nm_gejala);
  if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
  {
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do
   {
    Gejala gejala = new Gejala();
    gejala.setNama_gejala(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(nm_gejala)));
    gejala.setKode_gejala(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(kd_gejala)));


    listGejala.add(gejala);

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  return listGejala;

 }  

 public List<Gejala> Search(String Nama_gejala)
 {
  List<Gejala> listGejala = new ArrayList<Gejala>();

  Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_gejala, new String[] { 
          kd_gejala,
          nm_gejala }, 
          nm_gejala + " like ?", new String[] {"%"+ Nama_gejala +"%"}, null, null, null, null);
  if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
  {
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do
   {
       Gejala gejala = new Gejala();
        gejala.setNama_gejala(cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndexOrThrow(nm_gejala)));


        listGejala.add(gejala);

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  return listGejala;

 }

 public List<Penyakit> getAllPenyakit()
 {
  List<Penyakit> listPenyakit = new ArrayList<Penyakit>();

  Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_penyakit, new String[] {kd_penyakit, nm_penyakit, deskripsi, solusi, gambar
     }, null, null, null, null, nm_penyakit);
  if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
  {
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do
   {
    Penyakit penyakit = new Penyakit();
    penyakit.setNama_penyakit(cursor.getString(cursor
      .getColumnIndexOrThrow(nm_penyakit)));
    penyakit.setDeskripsi(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(deskripsi)));
    penyakit.setSolusi(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(solusi)));
    penyakit.setGambar(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(gambar)));


    listPenyakit.add(penyakit);

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  return listPenyakit;

 }  

 public List<Penyakit> Searching (String Nama_penyakit)
 {
  List<Penyakit> listPenyakit = new ArrayList<Penyakit>();

  Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_penyakit, new String[] { 
          kd_penyakit,
          nm_penyakit,
          deskripsi,
          solusi,
          gambar}, 
          nm_penyakit + " like ?", new String[] {"%"+ Nama_penyakit +"%"}, null, null, null, null);
  if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
  {
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do
   {
       Penyakit penyakit = new Penyakit();
        penyakit.setNama_penyakit(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(nm_penyakit)));
        penyakit.setDeskripsi(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(deskripsi)));
        penyakit.setSolusi(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(solusi)));
        penyakit.setGambar(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(gambar)));

        listPenyakit.add(penyakit);

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  return listPenyakit;

 }

 public double getMB(/*int kode_rule,*/ String kode_gejala)
 {
     /*
  Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_rule, new String[] 
          {kd_rule, ko_gejala, ko_penyakit, nilai_mb, nilai_md
     },  ko_gejala + " like ?", new String[] {"%"+ kode_gejala +"%"},
     null, null, null, null);

  double mb = 0;
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  mb = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nilai_mb));
 if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
  {
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do
   {
       mb = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nilai_mb));
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
*/
      Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_rule, new String[] {
              kd_rule, 
              ko_gejala, 
              ko_penyakit, 
              nilai_mb, 
              nilai_md
         },   ko_gejala + " = '"+kode_gejala+"'", null, null, null, null, null);

      double mb = 0;

      if(cursor != null){
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
              mb = cursor.getDouble(3);
          }
      }

  return mb;
 }

 public double getMD(/*int kode_rule,*/ String kode_gejala)
 {
  Cursor cursor = db.query(tabel_rule, new String[] {
          kd_rule, 
          ko_gejala, 
          ko_penyakit, 
          nilai_mb, 
          nilai_md
     },   ko_gejala + " = '"+kode_gejala+"'", null, null, null, null, null);

  double md = 0;
//  cursor.moveToFirst();
//  md = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nilai_md));
/*  
  if (cursor.getCount() >= 1)
  {
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   do
   {
       md = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nilai_md));
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
*/

  if(cursor != null){
      cursor.moveToFirst();
          md = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(nilai_md));
          System.out.print(nilai_md);
  }

  return md;

 }

}
```

Comment: You can save your image path it'd be easier to insert and retrieve , else you have to take blob field in db and save your image in it form of byte[].

Comment: Can I know the code of that? @Nisarg

Comment: form of byte[] or Image path ?

Comment: from image path @Nisarg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact details here but basically, if you want to store images in your database you must store the information as a 'blob' of bytes.

You'll need to convert between bytes and Bitmap when you read from the DB and Bitmap and bytes when you want to write to the DB.

A URI is usually used for a file coming from your device storage or somewhere on a server/website etc.

If this is what you're looking for and you'd like more detailed help just let me know and I can provide more info.

Comment: Yes, I mean like that. But would not that make database slow and take a lot of data? @seanAshmore

Comment: It depends on how many images you are using I guess but it should perform well enough for most use-cases.

Comment: I use about 100 images, okay I will try. Can you give me more info about it? @seanAshmore

Comment: Sorry this has taken so long. Hopefully these methods will help you to store bitmaps as strings and read strings and turn them into bitmaps.

Comment: <code>public final static String bitmapToString(Bitmap in){ ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); in.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes); return Base64.encodeToString(bytes.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT); } public final static Bitmap stringToBitmap(String in){ byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(in, Base64.DEFAULT); return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); }</code>

Comment: I'm very sorry for the formatting but I'm on my mobile. Put it into your android studio and it should be able to auto format it to make it more readable.

Comment: Where I should add that code? in DBAdapter? @seanAshmore

Comment: Yes if you make a column for your image, it's type will presumably be text. When you're writing to this column you would use the bitmapToString method. And when reading from it you would use stringToBitmap

Comment: Yes I have 'image' column as blob type. And then where should I store the image? In assets folder or drawable? @seanAshmore